# Android Google+ SignInButton. How to set size attribute in xml

Tags: android, google-plus

Here is a basic Google+ Android Sign-In button in XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In the class [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.html) it states that you can specify the size of the button as ICON_ONLY, STANDARD AND WIDE.

How do you do this using xml?

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to do it in XML.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonSize="wide"
        app:colorScheme="dark"/>
```

buttonSize => ("wide", "standard, "icon_only"), colorScheme = > ("light", "dark")

Comment: 'auto' also works for colorScheme.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of the methods on SignInButton around size and style:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.html

I'm not aware of any way to do this in XML.

Answer (score 1):

setSize() is a public method try using it at runtime through java as.

```
    ((com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button))
                   .setSize(STANDARD);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mSignInButton.setSize(1); // SIZE_WIDE
mSignInButton.setSize(2); // SIZE_ICON_ONLY
mSignInButton.setSize(0); // SIZE_STANDARD
```